# Not displaying SQL data through PHP when using a template file

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I have used a template.php file to create the layout of my page and then inserting the content through a $content variable which is stored in a separate file. This the example of that file:

```
<?php

$content =
'
    <table id="job_table">
        <tr>
          <th id="jobtitle">Catering Assistant</th>
          <th id="r_code">Ref Code: 14407773</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td id="location">Northampton</td>
          <td id="salery">£2,000 Monthly</td>       
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td id="description">Description</td>
            <td>
            Assist in catering for workers in canteen area.
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><a href="apply.php" class="applyButton">Apply Now!</a></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
';

include 'template.php';

?>
```

Then inside of my template I simply using echo to display the content:

```
<div id="content_area">
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
```

When I use the following code inside of my template.php file everything works as intended:

```
<div id="content_area">
                <?php echo $content; ?>

                <?php

                $server = '192.168.56.2';
                $username = 'student';
                $password = 'student';
                $schema = 'TravelCompanyDatabase';

                $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
                $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM user');

                foreach ($results as $row)
                {
                    echo '<p>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';
                }

                ?>
            </div>
```

[Working Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chHCx.png)

But when I use the same code within my content php file I get an error like this:

```
<?php

$title = "Jobs";
$content =
'
    <?php

    $server = '192.168.56.2';
    $username = 'student';
    $password = 'student';
    $schema = 'TravelCompanyDatabase';

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
    $results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM user');

    foreach ($results as $row)
    {
        echo '<p>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';
    }

    ?>
';

include 'template.php';

?>
```

[Webpage Displaying Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlZ6r.png)

Comment: Have you tried encasing your $content with double quotes rather than singles? I would say the reason why you are getting this error is because when it gets to the first single quote before the 192.168 it actually jumps out of the $content section causing the error.

Comment: You're trying to echo the variable $content which is stored in a separate file?  did you include the file containing the $content variable in the template.php file?

Comment: @WesleyMurch I believe that the php open and closing are both correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably better if you do something like this:

```
<?php
$title = "Jobs";
$content = ''; // Create an empty string

$server = '192.168.56.2';
$username = 'student';
$password = 'student';
$schema = 'TravelCompanyDatabase';

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM user');

foreach ($results as $row)
{    // Add every result to $content using .=
    $content .= '<p>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';
}

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thank you! You most probably definitely are right. You are a god send :)

Answer (score 0):

You are double opening the `<?php` tag.

Try this:

```
<?php
$title = "Jobs";
$server = '192.168.56.2';
$username = 'student';
$password = 'student';
$schema = 'TravelCompanyDatabase';

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password);
$results = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM user');

$content = '';
foreach ($results as $row) {
    $content.= '<p>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';
}

include 'template.php';

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using double quotes for the $content variable.

Comment: This gave a different error instead:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /srv/http/jobs.php on line 18

Comment: which refers to this line:  echo '<p>' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</p>';